# No Material widget found while using inkwell with showdialog in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show my custom dialog box in my app. I am using showDialog for the same. I want that whenever I click a button, this dialog box is shown. But it is giving me the error - `**No Material widget found.**`

I checked online and tried using scaffold in ask_doubt_dialog.dart, i.e. made scaffold a parent of  container in the file, but it was taking the whole screen for it. And when I reduced the size of container, it was showing blank opaque screen in the remaining portion, like this -

[image]

So, I chose backgroundcolor of scaffold as transparent, but I was not able to close it by clicking outside.

Here is ask_doubt_dialog.dart file -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_board_plus/styles.dart';

askDoubtDialog(context) {
  return showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: cardColor2,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(3)),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 200,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.9,
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Type your question here',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 1,
              color: tertiaryTextColor2,
              width: double.infinity,
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {

                  },
                  child: Container(
                    child: Text(
                      'Add an image'
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
  );
}
```

After making scaffold bg as transparent, and not able to click outside of it close it -

[image]

I am calling it like this -

```
child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    askDoubtDialog(context);
                  },
```

This is the exact error log -

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Type your question here"), dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery, UnmanagedRestorationScope], state: _TextFieldState#0e2af):
No Material widget found.

TextField widgets require a Material widget ancestor.
In material design, most widgets are conceptually "printed" on a sheet of material. In Flutter's material library, that material is represented by the Material widget. It is the Material widget that renders ink splashes, for instance. Because of this, many material library widgets require that there be a Material widget in the tree above them.

To introduce a Material widget, you can either directly include one, or use a widget that contains Material itself, such as a Card, Dialog, Drawer, or Scaffold.

The specific widget that could not find a Material ancestor was: TextField
  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Type your question here")
  dirty
  dependencies: [MediaQuery, UnmanagedRestorationScope]
  state: _TextFieldState#0e2af
The ancestors of this widget were: 
  : SizedBox
    width: 353.5
    height: 200.0
    renderObject: RenderConstrainedBox#9071d NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
  : Column
    direction: vertical
    mainAxisAlignment: start
    crossAxisAlignment: center
    renderObject: RenderFlex#e2f6d NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  : Padding
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0)
    dependencies: [Directionality]
    renderObject: RenderPadding#31a15 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  : Container
    bg: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xff2e2b47), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0))
  : MaterialApp
    state: _MaterialAppState#99820
  : ChangeNotifierProvider<APIData>
    value: Instance of 'APIData'
    listening to value
  : Consumer<AppLocale>
    dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<AppLocale?>]
  : MyApp
  : ChangeNotifierProvider<AppLocale>
    value: Instance of 'AppLocale'
    listening to value
  ...
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  TextField TextField:file:///C:/Users/Hp/AndroidStudioProjects/myboardplusv2/lib/visual_components/dialogs/ask_doubt_dialog.dart:19:22
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      debugCheckHasMaterial.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/debug.dart:29:7)
#1      debugCheckHasMaterial (package:flutter/src/material/debug.dart:50:4)
#2      _TextFieldState.build (package:flutter/src/material/text_field.dart:1115:12)
#3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4870:27)
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4754:15)
#5      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4928:11)
#6      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#7      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4735:5)
#8      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4919:11)
#9      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4729:5)
...     Normal element mounting (4 frames)
#13     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3790:14)
#14     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6422:36)
#15     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6433:32)
...     Normal element mounting (199 frames)
#214    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3790:14)
#215    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6422:36)
#216    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3540:18)
#217    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5845:32)
#218    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6445:17)
#219    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
#220    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4780:16)
#221    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4928:11)
#222    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#223    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4960:5)
#224    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
#225    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4780:16)
#226    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#227    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5108:5)
#228    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
#229    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4780:16)
#230    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#231    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5108:5)
#232    _InheritedNotifierElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:111:11)
#233    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
#234    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6291:14)
#235    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
#236    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4780:16)
#237    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4928:11)
#238    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#239    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4960:5)
#240    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
#241    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6291:14)
#242    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
#243    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6291:14)
#244    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
#245    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4780:16)
#246    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#247    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5108:5)
#248    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
#249    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4780:16)
#250    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4928:11)
#251    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#252    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2659:19)
#253    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:882:21)
#254    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:363:5)
#255    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#256    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1081:9)
#257    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:995:5)
#261    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:10)
#262    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
#263    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building _InkResponseStateWidget(gestures: [tap], mouseCursor: null, clipped to BoxShape.rectangle, dirty, state: _InkResponseState#0f1a8):
No Material widget found.

_InkResponseStateWidget widgets require a Material widget ancestor.
In material design, most widgets are conceptually "printed" on a sheet of material. In Flutter's material library, that material is represented by the Material widget. It is the Material widget that renders ink splashes, for instance. Because of this, many material library widgets require that there be a Material widget in the tree above them.

To introduce a Material widget, you can either directly include one, or use a widget that contains Material itself, such as a Card, Dialog, Drawer, or Scaffold.

The specific widget that could not find a Material ancestor was: _InkResponseStateWidget
  gestures: tap
  mouseCursor: null
  clipped to BoxShape.rectangle
  dirty
  state: _InkResponseState#0f1a8
The ancestors of this widget were: 
  : InkWell
  : Row
    direction: horizontal
    mainAxisAlignment: start
    crossAxisAlignment: center
    dependencies: [Directionality]
    renderObject: RenderFlex#5d8b0 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
  : Column
    direction: vertical
    mainAxisAlignment: start
    crossAxisAlignment: center
    renderObject: RenderFlex#e2f6d NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  : Padding
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0)
    dependencies: [Directionality]
    renderObject: RenderPadding#31a15 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  : Container
    bg: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xff2e2b47), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0))
  : MaterialApp
    state: _MaterialAppState#99820
  : ChangeNotifierProvider<APIData>
    value: Instance of 'APIData'
    listening to value
  : Consumer<AppLocale>
    dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<AppLocale?>]
  : MyApp
  : ChangeNotifierProvider<AppLocale>
    value: Instance of 'AppLocale'
    listening to value
  ...
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  InkWell InkWell:file:///C:/Users/Hp/AndroidStudioProjects/myboardplusv2/lib/visual_components/dialogs/ask_doubt_dialog.dart:32:17
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      debugCheckHasMaterial.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/debug.dart:29:7)
#1      debugCheckHasMaterial (package:flutter/src/material/debug.dart:50:4)
#2      InkResponse.debugCheckContext (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:624:12)
#3      _InkResponseState.build (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1070:36)
#4      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4870:27)
#5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4754:15)
#6      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4928:11)
#7      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#8      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4735:5)
#9      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4919:11)
#10     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4729:5)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#17     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3790:14)
#18     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6422:36)
#19     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6433:32)
#20     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3790:14)
#21     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6422:36)
#22     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6433:32)
...     Normal element mounting (199 frames)
#221    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3790:14)
#222    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6422:36)
#223    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3540:18)
#224    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5845:32)
#225    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6445:17)
#226    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
#227    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4780:16)
#228    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4928:11)
#229    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#230    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4960:5)
#231    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
#232    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4780:16)
#233    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#234    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5108:5)
#235    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
#236    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4780:16)
#237    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#238    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5108:5)
#239    _InheritedNotifierElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:111:11)
#240    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
#241    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6291:14)
#242    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
#243    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4780:16)
#244    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4928:11)
#245    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#246    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4960:5)
#247    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
#248    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6291:14)
#249    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
#250    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6291:14)
#251    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
#252    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4780:16)
#253    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#254    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5108:5)
#255    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3501:15)
#256    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4780:16)
#257    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4928:11)
#258    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#259    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2659:19)
#260    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:882:21)
#261    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:363:5)
#262    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#263    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1081:9)
#264    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:995:5)
#268    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:10)
#269    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
#270    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
====================================================================================================
I/flutter ( 5561): token eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiMWQyNmNjMDUtNjY0OC00MTA0LThhMGItOTMwMjFjMzk3ODY1IiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOjk1NDk0NDE5MjIsImV4cCI6MTY0NzkzMTkwNCwiZW1haWwiOiIiLCJjb250YWN0Ijo5NTQ5NDQxOTIyfQ.WeJuZp2aOFaa29Ko0zysyaJSxz0SVvLNUrf8TfGcM1k
D/EGL_emulation( 5561): app_time_stats: avg=206.76ms min=13.14ms max=1307.28ms count=10

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 99617 pixels on the right.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Row Row:file:///C:/Users/Hp/AndroidStudioProjects/myboardplusv2/lib/visual_components/dialogs/ask_doubt_dialog.dart:30:13
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.horizontal.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#5d8b0 relayoutBoundary=up1 OVERFLOWING
...  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 201.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=382.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  size: Size(382.7, 100000.0)
...  direction: horizontal
...  mainAxisAlignment: start
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: center
...  textDirection: ltr
...  verticalDirection: down
  child 1: RenderErrorBox#d0d6c
    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
    size: Size(100000.0, 100000.0)
◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 99466 pixels on the bottom.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column Column:file:///C:/Users/Hp/AndroidStudioProjects/myboardplusv2/lib/visual_components/dialogs/ask_doubt_dialog.dart:14:16
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#e2f6d OVERFLOWING
...  parentData: offset=Offset(5.0, 5.0) (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=382.7, h=735.5)
...  size: Size(382.7, 735.5)
...  direction: vertical
...  mainAxisAlignment: start
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: center
...  verticalDirection: down
◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
====================================================================================================
```

Comment: does your app has ``MaterialApp()`` widget?

Comment: @OMiShah yes, it does.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Wrap your `Container` inside [`AlertDialog`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html) Widget, Try below code

Your AlertDialog method:

```
 askDoubtDialog(context) {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Some Text'),
        content: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.blue,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(3)),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 200,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Type your question here',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 1,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  width: double.infinity,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: Container(
                        child: Text('Add an image'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Your Widget:

```
   InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          askDoubtDialog(context);
        },
        child: Text('Pressed Me'),
      ),
```

Your Result screen-> [image]