# A renderflex overflowed error when typing in an AlertBox in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have made an AlertBox for my showDialog in Flutter, on which I have a text field. Whenever I open my keyboard to type, pixels overflow. What should I do to avoid this? I have made `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,` in my Scaffold, but the error is caused by the alert box, which doesn't have a scaffold. Can someone tell me what should I do?

Here is my code -

```
InkWell(
    onTap: () {
       askDoubtDialog(context);
    },

askDoubtDialog(context) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
          //title: Text('Alert'),
          insetPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
          content: Builder(
            builder: (context) => Container(
              height: 330,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.9,
              color: cardColor2,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 10),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 160,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.9,
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'Type your question here',
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                            width: 150.0,
                            height: 100.0,
                            child: Image.file(
                              _image,
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 1,
                            color: tertiaryTextColor2,
                            width: double.infinity,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 13.0),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  _onAlertPress(context);
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Add an image',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: backgroundColor2,
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 10,
                              ),
                              InkWell(
                                onTap: () {

                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Post',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: backgroundColor2,
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: brandYellow,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
  }
```

I tried to wrap the container (of height 330) inside `SingleChildScrollView`, but it didn't worked.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71553496/13997210) on your question its work very well.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `Scaffold` body with `SingleChildScrollView`.